# Characterization of compact operators by their spectra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

In any functional analysis book there is usually a section devoted to the study of the properties of the spectrum of compact operators.

1. Is there any spectral characterization of compact (self-adjoint) operators?

Here is an example of what I have in mind

2. Suppose $T$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator whose eigenvalues have finite multiplicity and $0$ is the only limit point of its spectrum. Then (perhaps with some more spectral conditions) $T$ is a compact operator.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for self-adjoint $T$, (2) is equivalent to $T$ being compact.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks! Do you use the spectral theorem to prove the equivalence?

Comment: Yes, if (2) holds, then you can approximate $T$ by finite rank operators would be a good argument.